# how to make buttons extend to full width in mobile view while not end pc using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to apply text end or push the buttom to end in pc view and make each buttons take whole width and stack upon each other  in mobile view  for  two  href buttons inside   ! any idea??

```
    <div class="row flex-between-end ps-0 pe-0">
        <div class="col-md-5">
             <label class="col-form-label text-facebook">@wordInfo["Title"]</label>
         </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 ps-sm-0"> 
         
            <a href="@(ViewData["ROOT_URL"])menu/menuform/@Common.CommonConst.Mode.PUB_C_REGIST/" 
            class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-2  ms-1 float-md-end ">
<span class="fas fa-plus " data- 
            fa-transform="shrink-3"></span> @wordInfo["Regist"]</a>
     
           <a href="@(ViewData["ROOT_URL"])menu/menusublist/" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-2 
          float-md-end"><span class="fa fa-bars" data-fa-transform="shrink-3"></span> 
          @wordInfo["MenuSubList"]</a>
            </div>
```

pc view ok

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D53xz.png)

should  looks like this in mobile view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whI6u.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this class **mobile** to label(Menu list) & a tag(Sub,Reg).

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
.mobile {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}
}
```

This will make them vertical when **screen-width<=800px**, change the vaue if you need to.